# ICloudStorageAccessToken Open says Null reference

Tags: c#, dropbox, sharpbox

I have a problem of opening a dropbox folder.  It a code that generates an exe. Basically when the exe is executed, it starts to download a package stored in a dropbox folder. Here is my code:

```
    _storage = new CloudStorage();

    var dropBoxCredentials = new DropBoxCredentials();

    dropBoxCredentials.ConsumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    dropBoxCredentials.ConsumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    dropBoxCredentials.UserName = "someusername";
    dropBoxCredentials.Password = "somepassword";

    DropBoxConfiguration configuration = DropBoxConfiguration.GetStandardConfiguration();

    //open the dropbox connection
    _storage.Open(configuration, dropBoxCredentials);
```

I am sorry that I have to hide the confidential information, but I assume they are correct. So the problem occurs at `_storage.Open(configuration, dropBoxCredentials);` It says:
![enter image description here][1]

I checked the "`configuration`" and "`dropBoxCredentials`", and they are not Null, and so is "`_storage`". 
So I am confused, what is the problem here exactly? Thanks a lot.

Edit; Here is the stack trace:

```
at AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.StorageProvider.DropBox.DropBoxToken..ctor(OAuthToken token, DropBoxBaseCredentials baseCreds)
at AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.StorageProvider.DropBox.Logic.DropBoxStorageProviderService.AuthorizeAndGetSession(DropBoxCredentials credentials, DropBoxConfiguration configuration)
at AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.StorageProvider.DropBox.Logic.DropBoxStorageProviderService.Authorize(DropBoxCredentials credentials, DropBoxConfiguration configuration)
at AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.StorageProvider.DropBox.Logic.DropBoxStorageProviderService.CreateSession(ICloudStorageCredentials credentials, ICloudStorageConfiguration configuration)
at AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.StorageProvider.GenericStorageProvider.Open(ICloudStorageConfiguration configuration, ICloudStorageCredentials credentials)
at AppLimit.CloudComputing.SharpBox.CloudStorage.Open(ICloudStorageConfiguration configuration, ICloudStorageCredentials credentials)
at WebUpdater.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\\TIS\\Tools\\WebUpdater\\WebUpdater\\Program.cs:line 52
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: You mean the callstack? It a web update exe. Basically when the exe is executed, it starts to download a package stored in a dropbox folder. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, I mean the stack trace. You can view it via "View Detail..." in the exception popup you showed a screenshot of. Alternatively you can just click the last link "Copy exception detail to the clipboard" and paste it here.

Comment: I see. I posted it as a picture. Does it help?

Comment: What you show is the complete exception. I need the stack trace. Have a look at the picture. From the top, locate the first occurence of "StackTrace". That string is what I need. The complete string, not just what is seen on the screenshot. I am trying to find out if the exception is thrown inside the `Open` method.

Comment: I see. How about now?

Comment: Better. I fixed it to be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the exception is originating from inside the SharpBox assembly.

A `NullReferenceException` always indicates some kind of bug and as such you should consider creating an issue on the SharpBox website.

Comment: @NickTsui: You don't. Make sure you are using the latest version. If that doesn't help, file a bug report.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot man. Although I am not at the latest version, but I think there is probably something wrong with our IT, since my code works fine till yesterday. I really appreciate help. One quick question: Where do you see in the stack trace that the problem comes from SharpBox Assembly?

Comment: @NickTsui: The stack trace contains the method called directly before the exception at the top. The next line specifies the method that called the method in which the exception has been thrown. You can see the call to `CloudStorage.Open` somewhere in the middle of the stack trace. This tells you: Your code didn't throw the exception. If it did, it wouldn't have entered the `Open` method.

Comment: So basically, because CloudStorage.Open gets executed, and this function is inside the SharpBox assembly, so in that case, I know that my code does not have problem whereas it is the assembly that causes the problem?

Comment: @NickTsui: Thanks, that's kind of you to say :)